# Ensure that mobs don't spawn on farm land

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I'm playing Minecraft with a mod called [Advent of Ascension](https://adventofascension.gamepedia.com/Mobs) that has mobs that can spawn regardless of light level.

Is there a way to make sure that these mobs don't spawn on my crops or my grass blocks (so that the sheep can regrow their wool).

Comment: Which Minecraft version? Farmland was somewhat recently changed to be less than one block high, so mobs (not "mods" BTW) can't spawn on it anyway. Also, what are your restrictions? Can there be glass blocks directly above the crops for example?

Comment: @FabianRöling  1.12.2, as long as the design doesn't make it harder to manage the crops its fine. But i was more concerned about the sheep

Comment: Have you tested whether mobs spawn on farmland in your modded version? What about if everything is filled with crops? And for the grass blocks you can just place torches or signs or anything like that on every block.

Comment: @FabianRöling Made a world with grass blocks and torches above them, mobs were still spawning. Also made one with farmland and it looks like mobs can't spawn on it.

Comment: Can they spawn on bottom slabs?

Comment: I'm not sure if sheep can eat grass through e.g. carpet. You could try blocks with pretty small hitboxes, like for example iron bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if mobs ignore light levels (like in the Nether or in your modded case all mobs), they still can't spawn inside blocks with a hitbox (with some [buggy exceptions](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-148955)). One that affects not many other things is carpet, for example sheep can still eat through it.

Farmland was changed to be only 15/16 of a block high in 1.10.1, so mobs should already not spawn on it. If they do anyway in your modded game, you could try for example putting end rods above the crops, because usually mobs cannot spawn if there isn't space for them at least two blocks high, not even baby zombies or bats. If they do it anyway, even with crops on the field, there's probably no way to prevent it.